# NSInvalidArgumentException while applying filter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, core-image

i was writing the code to add filters to the pictures. Here is the code

```
func applyFilter(index: Int){
    print("Applying Filter....")
    //let context = CIContext()
    // 1
    //below two lines will refer the code to GPU instead of cpu
    let openGLContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
    let context = CIContext(eaglContext: openGLContext!)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: pickerFilters[index])!
    // 2

    //filter.setValue(0.8, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
    let image = selectedImageArray[selectedIndex]                          // 3
    filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let result = filter.outputImage                                   // 4 this line and the below line are problematic
    let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result!, from: (result?.extent)!)    // 5
    //        //load this image to imageview
    imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
    print("Filter Applied")
}
```

The code gives me an error when i click the collectionView to select a filter. What i figured is that the exception is at any of these two lines

```
let result = filter.outputImage                                   // 4 this line and the below line are problematic
    let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result!, from: (result?.extent)!)    // 5
```

if i remove these two lines then the program works fine but as you can see filter will not be applied. Please let me know what i am doing wrong?
 Thanks

> Edit
>   It says something like unrecognized selector sent to instance ....
>   Below is the detail of what is produced in the output window when exception occurrs.

```
Applying Filter....
2017-03-04 21:54:28.058 AVFrameWorkPractice[1223:31319] -[UIImage     extent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000095720
2017-03-04 21:54:28.145 AVFrameWorkPractice[1223:31319] *** Terminating     app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:     '-[UIImage extent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000095720'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d693d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d0f521e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d703f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d619005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d6a6a08 __forwarding_prep_1___ + 120
5   CoreImage                           0x000000010db9f9a4 -[CICMYKHalftone outputImage] + 336
6   AVFrameWorkPractice                 0x000000010bc49e7e _TFC19AVFrameWorkPractice20CustomEffectsCreator11applyFilterfT5indexSi_T_ + 1038
7   AVFrameWorkPractice                 0x000000010bc4962b _TFC19AVFrameWorkPractice20CustomEffectsCreator14collectionViewfTCSo16UICollectionView15didSelectItemAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_T_ + 1227
8   AVFrameWorkPractice                 0x000000010bc496a7 _TToFC19AVFrameWorkPractice20CustomEffectsCreator14collectionViewfTCSo16UICollectionView15didSelectItemAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_T_ + 87
9   UIKit                               0x000000010e9526e4 -[UICollectionView _selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 702
10  UIKit                               0x000000010e97d4d2 -[UICollectionView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 649
11  UIKit                               0x000000010e230f6b forwardTouchMethod + 348
12  UIKit                               0x000000010e231034 -[UIResponder touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 49
13  UIKit                               0x000000010e230f6b forwardTouchMethod + 348
14  UIKit                               0x000000010e231034 -[UIResponder touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 49
15  UIKit                               0x000000010e54b304 _UIGestureEnvironmentSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 5645
16  UIKit                               0x000000010e545fcb _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1472
17  UIKit                               0x000000010e5459c3 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 521
18  UIKit                               0x000000010e544ba6 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 286
19  UIKit                               0x000000010e08ac1d -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3989
20  UIKit                               0x000000010e0379ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
21  UIKit                               0x000000010e82472d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
22  UIKit                               0x000000010e81d463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d638761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d61d98c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d61ce76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d61c884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
27  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112734a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
28  UIKit                               0x000000010e019c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
29  AVFrameWorkPractice                 0x000000010bc4be4f main + 111
30  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112d2868d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

(lldb)

Comment: Any exclamation mark can crash the app. If a method might return `nil` use optional binding. If a method can return `nil` but should not, it's a design (developer) error.

Comment: Are you sure your `selectedImageArray` contains `CIImage`s ? The exception dump seems you have set a `UIImage` for `kCIInputImageKey`.

Comment: No, it contains UIImages. Should i convert them to CIImage? Will try that. thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @OOPer that solved my problem. Can you put that to an answer so that i can accept that?

Comment: Have you checked if your code works for all filters you want to apply? The part `(result?.extent)!` (which is the same as `result!.extent`) may not work for some filters.

Comment: It does not work for all filters. How can i do that? Can you help me? It gives error <CIImage: 0x600000008680 extent [infinite]> value. I don't understand.

Comment: Use the `extent` of the input `CIImage`. The `extent` of the `outputImage` of some filters can be infinite.

Comment: Thank you @OOPer. I really appreciate the help. Can you help me how should i get started with image and video manipulation in swift? What is the best way? I want to have full command over AVFoundation and CoreImage. Please do help me in this regards.

Comment: In fact, I have learnt all such things in my comments while experimenting some topics taken from StackOverflow or Apple's dev forums. Utilizing such online resources would be my best recommendation. Anyway, please take some time to post an answer by yourself.

Comment: Okay, thank you @OOPer by the way.

Comment: Hi @OOPer can you help me with something? I want to make a slide show app in swift. What i have achieved by now is create a video from images and add background music. But the images just show and disappear. Very boring. I want to apply some transitions, animations like in real apps. Can you help me with that?

Comment: If your issue is some specific programming topic and you post another question here in StackOverflow (or somewhere I visit), I will make my best effort to help you solve the issue. Maybe that's all what I can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was passing UIImage instead of CIImage like

```
let image = selectedImageArray[selectedIndex]                          
filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
```

what must be done was

```
let image = selectedImageArray[selectedIndex]// 3
let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)
filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
```

Then it works fine. And also as @Ooper said

> We must pass extent of input image instead of output Image as extent of output image can be infinite.